Flink table API state management
I have few big MySQL tables, which I'd like to join between each other to produce result. I also want to receive infrequently coming updates for records which was created during previous year.
Current approach is to use MySQL CDC Connector, current job setup is parallelism 5 with 5 task managers and 8Gb heap size per each TM, what gives 40Gb in total.
But the job starts to fail after processing certain amount of records due to not enough memory. I see that job state is always growing. Is there a way to truncate Flink tables? Or what is recommended way to approach this problem?
Flink version is 1.17.2
CDC version is    3.0.0
